# BaseX and Java: could modules be used in Java API of BaseX

Tags: java, basex

Say, I have 2 .xqy files. One .xqy references functions from another file by importing module.
I want to port my .xqy files to use Java API of BaseX. I found some [Java_Examples](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Java_Examples) of BaseX. In  [RunQueries.java](https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/blob/master/basex-examples/src/main/java/org/basex/examples/local/RunQueries.java) the query is placed in a string variable. Could I reference a function in another module like:

```
    String query = "mymodule:testFunction()";

    // Process the query by using the database command
    System.out.println("\n* Use the database command:");

    query(query);
```